# How to deny access on Payara by ip to an application?

Tags: glassfish

I want to deny access to an application using virtual servers on payara and just allows some IPs to consume this application.

**The scenery is:**

When I try to see the URL http://host:port/ContextRoot, the access is denied. It's OK response with error 403.

**The issue is:**

When I try to see the URL http://host:port/ContextRoot/OperationOne.wsdl, I'm able to see the WSDL definition (is allowed).

I executed this steps to create this scenery:

1. the instance was created
2. the conf ports was created
3. the restriction by ip was created
4. the deployment was executed